# Invalid Use of Property error on Shape.OnAction

Tags: vba, properties, shapes

I'm trying to put a macro to a shape from vba but I received this error "Invalid use of property", why?

 **Class CContainer Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateContainer()
Dim s As Shape ' shape container
Dim t As Shape 'text container
Dim sr As Variant 'container for grouping
Dim w As Worksheet
Set w = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set s = w.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 100, 100)
With s
s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
s.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 100)
s.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
s.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
s.Line.Weight = 0.5
s.Name = "ShapeExample"
End With
Set t = w.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, s.Left + 10, s.Top + 10, s.Width - 20, 20)
With t
t.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 100)
t.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
t.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Connector"
t.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 10
t.TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
t.Name = "TextShapeExample"
End With
Set sr = w.Shapes.Range(Array("ShapeExample", "TextShapeExample")).Group
sr.Name = "ContainerExample"

t.OnAction "MsgCall" '<-- here the error occurs
End Sub

Sub MsgCall()
MsgBox "Hello There"
End Sub
```

and here's the module from where I want to call it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub example()
Dim connector As CContainer
Set connector = New CContainer
connector.CreateContainer

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you missing an equal sign?
t.OnAction = "MsgCall"

Comment: no, that'd cause an `application defined / object error `, but thanks @CodyG.

Comment: Application defined / object error from the  Set sr = w.Shapes.Range(Array("ShapeExample", "TextShapeExample")).Group line.

Comment: i found the answer, but is not what I wanted, the problem is that a procedure cannot be called (at least in my example) from the same class module, I moved the subroutine `MsgCall` to a new std Module and then i modified my code in the line-error changing it for this `OnAction = "MsgCall"` and then it works

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit to this:

```
With Worksheets(1).Shapes(1)

.OnAction "MsgCall" '<-- no more error here

End With
```

Now, I'm getting a different error: `Grouping is disabled for selected shapes` for this code:

```
Set sr = w.Shapes.Range(Array("ShapeExample", "TextShapeExample")).Group
```

Comment: I still receiving the same error even changing my code for what you proposed to me, `invalid use of property`

Comment: I found the answer, but is not what I wanted, the problem is that a procedure cannot be called (at least in my example) from the same class module, I moved the subroutine `MsgCall` to a new std Module and then i modified my code in the line-error changing it for this `OnAction = "MsgCall"` and then it works, Thank you for your help anyway, because it guide me to find the answer